# How to get a measure for the average "frequency" for wave-like data that changes frequency constantly over time?

Tags: time-series, frequency, wavelet

Sure I can measure the average amplitude, but I'm interested in trying to get a measure for the frequency given the list of amplitude values within a certain time frame. Any ideas? Maybe not even frequency exactly but I'd like to measure the intensity and speed of the cycle of the wave.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to do a frequency decomposition of your data. The `fft` command in $R$ should get you what you want. The more difficult question is how to address variations in that frequency to determine the "average" frequency -- since you might want to look at a range of frequencies together as representing one frequency with some minor variations, and you might want to ignore some higher frequencies as noise.